# To compare a set of condition and create multiple outputs in IF ELSE statement

Tags: r

I have a simplified data frame 1 (df1):

```
set.seed(100)  
df1 = data.frame(greater_than_or_equal_to= unique(cummax(sample.int(100))))
df1$less_than = c(df1$greater_than_or_equal_to[2:nrow(df1)], 
                  df1$greater_than_or_equal_to[nrow(df1)]+3)
df1$score1 =  round(runif(10,1,10),1)
df1$score2 =  round(runif(10,2,20),1)
df1 = df1[1:5,]

df1
greater_than_or_equal_to less_than score1 score2
                    31        55    3.9   17.1
                    55        77    4.5   16.5
                    77        79    1.4    3.5
                    79        93    4.3    6.3
                    93        94    6.1   19.4
```

I have another simplified data frame (df2):

```
df2 = data.frame(benchmark = runif(5,31,94))
df2 = round(df2,1)
df2
benchmark
  50.4
  47.2
  65.8
  34.6
  60.5
```

I want to compare benchmark in df2 to the range between the first two columns in df1 and create multiple new columns in df2 using score1 and score2 in df1.

An example code and output:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)){
  if (df2$benchmark[i] < 55) {
    df2$cav[i] = df1$score1[1]
    df2$gold[i] = df1$score2[1]
  } else if (df2$benchmark[i] < 77) {
    df2$cav[i] = df1$score1[2]
    df2$gold[i] = df1$score2[2]
  } else if (df2$benchmark[i] < 79) {
    df2$cav[i] = df1$score1[3]
    df2$gold[i] = df1$score2[3]
  } else if (df2$benchmark[i] < 93) {
    df2$cav[i] = df1$score1[4]
    df2$gold[i] = df1$score2[4]
  } else {
    df2$cav[i] = df1$score1[5]
    df2$gold[i] = df1$score2[5]
  }
}

df2
benchmark gold cav
     50.4 17.1 3.9
     47.2 17.1 3.9
     65.8 16.5 4.5
     34.6 17.1 3.9
     60.5 16.5 4.5
```

This code generates what I wanted but it is not efficient if df1 and df2 has say 1000 rows to match. Any idea how I can scale this process efficiently?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure that the columns you are working with are sorted and make some gains there with a slightly different loop strategy. Here is some code with 5000 rows each. It runs in a few seconds, which is usually good enough for most people.

```
set.seed(100)  
df1 = data.frame(greater_than_or_equal_to= sort(runif(5000, 5, 1500)))
df1$less_than = c(df1$greater_than_or_equal_to[2:nrow(df1)], 
                  df1$greater_than_or_equal_to[nrow(df1)]+3)
df1$score1 =  round(runif(5000,1,10),1)
df1$score2 =  round(runif(5000,2,20),1)
df1 = df1[1:5000,]

df2 = data.frame(benchmark = runif(5000,1,940))
df2 = round(df2,1)
```

Here is the new loop.

```
#init the new columns
df2$cav<-NA
df2$gold<-NA

#sort the cols we need to be sorted
df1<-df1[order(df1$less_than),]
df2<-df2[order(df2$benchmark),]

#loop through df1 and fill in the corresponding values
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  val<-df1[i,]$less_than
  rows<-which(is.na(df2$cav) & df2$benchmark < val)

  #might not be any matches
  if(length(rows) > 0){
    df2[rows,]$cav<-df1[i,]$score1
    df2[rows,]$gold<-df1[i,]$score2
  }

  #we can stop when it is full
  if(all(!is.na(df2))){
    break
  }
}
```